# MaxScale login as root or other users

Tags: mariadb, galera, maxscale

I installed `MaxScale 2.4.4` with `Galera Cluster`. I can access to galera with maxscale user but I can't login with other users to maxscale. I created a user in galera and another user with same username with maxctrl but it return Access denied error. How I can create users for applications in maxscale 2.4.4.

maxscale.cnf

```
[maxscale]
threads=1

[Galera-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=galeramon
servers=server1,server2,server3
user=maxscale
password=qwe123
disable_master_failback=1

[Galera-Service]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=server1,server2,server3
user=maxscale
password=qwe123

[Galera-Listener]
type=listener
#router=readwritesplit
service=Galera-Service
protocol=MySQLClient
port=3306

[Write-Service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
router_options=master
servers=server1, server2, server3
user=maxscale
password=qwe123

[Read-Service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
router_options=slave
servers=server1, server2, server3
user=maxscale
password=qwe123

#[Splitter-Service]
#type=service
#router=readwritesplit
#servers=server1,server2,server3
#user=maxscale
#password=qwe123

#[Splitter-Listener]
#type=listener
#service=Splitter-Service
#protocol=MariaDBClient
#port=3306

[CLI]
type=service
router=cli

[CLI-Listener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
address=0.0.0.0
port=6603

[server1]
type=server
address=192.168.122.93
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[server2]
type=server
address=192.168.122.17
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[server3]
type=server
address=192.168.122.13
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend
```

I found `enable_root_user=1` for login to maxscale with root user but I don't know where should I add it;

```
maxctrl list servers
┌─────────┬────────────────┬──────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────┐
│ Server  │ Address        │ Port │ Connections │ State                   │ GTID │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────┤
│ server1 │ 192.168.122.93 │ 3306 │ 0           │ Master, Synced, Running │      │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────┤
│ server2 │ 192.168.122.17 │ 3306 │ 0           │ Slave, Synced, Running  │      │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────┤
│ server3 │ 192.168.122.13 │ 3306 │ 0           │ Slave, Synced, Running  │      │
└─────────┴────────────────┴──────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────────┴──────┘
```

maxscale runs at `192.168.122.222` and I want all applications connect to this address with thier own user;

Comment: Check the "hostname" in the grant tables.

Comment: @RickJames Which hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked same question in stackoverflow. It trun out the problem was from maxscale user permissions.

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.user TO 'maxscale'@'maxscalehost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'maxscale'@'maxscalehost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.tables_priv TO 'maxscale'@'maxscalehost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.roles_mapping TO 'maxscale'@'maxscalehost';
GRANT SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO 'maxscale'@'maxscalehost';
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59540995/5456910